# Poke opcodes into memory

Tags: memory, assembly, lisp, common-lisp, nasm

Hi I am trying to understand whether it is possible to take instruction opcodes and 'poke' them into memory or smehow convert them to a binary program. I have found an abandoned lisp project here: http://common-lisp.net/viewvc/cl-x86-asm/cl-x86-asm/ which takes x86 asm instructions and converts them into opcodes (please see example below). The project does not go further to actually complete the creation of the binary executable. Hence I would need to do that 'manually' Any ideas can help me. Thanks.

```
 ;; assemble some code in it
(cl-x86-asm::assemble-forms 
  '((.Entry :PUSH :EAX)
    (:SUB :EAX #XFFFEA)
    (:MOV :EAX :EBX)
    (:POP :EAX)
    (:PUSH :EAX)
    (.Exit :RET))
```

Processing...

```
;; print the assembled segment
(cl-x86-asm::print-segment)

* Segment type DATA-SEGMENT
Segment size 0000000C bytes
50 81 05 00 0F FF EA 89
03 58 50 C3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned that it can be done using CFFI/FFI for example the very simple asm code:

```
(:movl 12 :eax)
(:ret)
```

This will be converted to the following sequence of octets: #(184 12 0 0 0 195) which in hex it is: #(B8 C 0 0 0 C3). The next step is to send it to a location in memory as such:

```
(defparameter pointer (cffi:foreign-alloc :unsigned-char :initial-contents #(184 12 0 0 0 195)))
;; and then execute it as such to return the integer 12:
(cffi:foreign-funcall-pointer pointer () :int)
=> result: 12
```

Thanks to the experts in #lisp (freenode irc channel) for helping out with this solution.

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, but what do you use to generate the vector from the assembly in the first part of your answer?  Does cffi support that?

Comment: @Joshua although some lisps can disassemble some functions to opcodes, the assembly opcodes are not and cannot be generated by cffi. you need to read and use your hardware instruction manual.

Answer (score 5):

Clozure Common Lisp for example has this built-in. This is usually called *LAP*, *Lisp Assembly Program*.

See `defx86lapfunction`.

Example:

```
(defx86lapfunction fast-mod ((number arg_y) (divisor arg_z))
  (xorq (% imm1) (% imm1))
  (mov (% number) (% imm0))
  (div (% divisor))
  (mov (% imm1) (% arg_z))
  (single-value-return))
```

SBCL can do some similar with *VOP* (Virtual Operations).

http://g000001.cddddr.org/2011-12-08

Comment: Thanks Rainier, those are 2 good examples. The advantage of that library I mentioned above is portability in that it is not dependent on specific implementation details.

Comment: @francogrex: Sure, but you did not ask for a portable library. You asked whether it is possible. M aybe you should rephrase your question?

Comment: I am thinking of something like Basic's POKE command to poke machine code directly into RAM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE

Comment: There is no such thing in *standard* Common Lisp.